# Emit from observer after callback returns

Tags: angular, sockets, observable

I have a component, called MyComponent. This component has a form with a submit button. In the `onSubmit()` function for this button, i am calling a `"myService.postData()"`. subscribe (...) etc.

The problem is with the service code. The "myService postData()" method should return an Observable but there is some complication here because the service is using a socket (socket.io) to send data to the server and get an acknowledgment. For this, I pass a callback function to the socket. emit as mentioned in socket.io documentation. The observable is supposed to return this response (received in the callback ) but here I have a problem because of asynchronous programming, how to return the response in the observable in the callback. I have tried a few things but they don't seem to work. Please find the code of the service as follows:

```
export class MyService {

  constructor(private socketService: SocketService) { }

  postData(newData: any ): Observable<any> {

    var myObservable: Observable<any>;

    this.socketService.getSocket().emit('post-data', newData,(response:any) => {
    //server will return a json object with values:  {status:''} which will be the response
    // that is passed to the MyComponent subscribe method

      myObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
        observer.next(response);

        //return myObservable gives error because then not all paths of postData() return a value.
      });

    });

    return myObservable; //this is undefined when it is received by MyComponent
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use the ngx.socket.io events ?
Here is the lib :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

All you need is to watch some data from the socket object :

```js
this.socket.fromEvent('message')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
postData(newData: any ): Observable {
  const subject$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1); 
  this.socketService.getSocket().emit('post-data', newData,(response:any) => {
    subject$.next(response);
  });

  return subject$.asObservable();
}
```